# Where to put robot.txt and sitemap.xml for wordpress installed in its own directory

Tags: directory, sitemap, robots.txt

My website is setup where wordpress is installed in it's own subdirectory, but the content is served as though it's at the domain root.
(This [wordpress codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) details the configuration)

Wordpress Url: `https://www.example.com/wordpress`
Site Url:      `https://www.example.com`

So in this case, urls get re-written to NOT include `/wordpress` in the url it serves pages from (although image urls *do* include it:  `https://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/...`).

URL for a page is:  `www.example.com/mypage/`
NOT:                `www.example.com/wordpress/mypage/`
but image link is:  `www.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/25/image1.jpg`

**Question:**
Do I put `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` in the "webiste root" directory on my server (`example.com`)
or its `wordpress` directory (`example.com/wordpress`) ?

I cannot find this particular case in any searches.
Also trial and error is not helping, because I get conflicting results from various sitemap and robot validators.

Additionally, it seems some plugin or some part of WordPress insists on creating Virtual sitemap (`sitemap.xml.gz`) and robot (`robot.txt`) files, which further exasperates my efforts to **definitively determine** the proper location to place these files for this common, but non-standard of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely place your robot.txt file as well as the sitemap.xml file into your websites root directory and **NOT** the WordPress directory.

When a robot visits your site, the first place it checks is http://sitename.com/robots.txt, hence you want to keep these files at the root of your domain.

You can also disallow what the robot has access to

```
    User-agent: *    # applies to all robots
    Disallow: /      # disallow indexing of all pages

    Disallow: wordpress/wp-admin/
    Disallow: wordpress/wp-includes/
    Disallow: wordpress/wp-content/plugins/
```

[W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.1)

Comment: Hmm... The logic of your explanation sounds inverted *to me*.  Could you help me understand where/how I'm thinking about this incorrectly? The way I see it, htaccess intercepts the request for `/sitemap.xml` but instead (as usual) serves up files from `/wordpress`, ie: `/wordpress/sitemap.xml`, Which implies *in my mind* that I would need to place sitemap and robot files inside `/wordpress`. Not root.

Comment: The way I understand it, I actually never actually serve anything from root. (htaccess and index.php prevent that?). Then again, the only stuff I (usually) ever (intentionally) serve are from WordPress. So I don't really know how "it" works for any non-wordpress-generated files/requests.  Thanks for helping me clear my foggy thinking.

Comment: So wait, you're saying my server finds the file in root, then passes the file itself to WordPress ? Then WordPress handles it?

Comment: Ok. so more experimentation. It looks like if a requested file exists in the root directory, it just serves it up.  If not, it forwards the request to /wordpress where WordPress intercepts the request, and attempts to process it.  If it is an existing page, it serves that page, otherwise it serves a 404 page (usually styled by the theme).  I got at this by placing `file1.txt` in root, and `file2.txt` in `/wordpress`.  `file1` displays its contents in my browser;but `file2.txt` showed me a 404 page from my site.

Comment: So, if I have `sitemap.xml` in root, my server probably just serves that right up.  Same for `robots.txt`.
If I don't have `sitemap.xml` in root, WordPress might generate one (depending on plugins or maybe even wordpress itself). And either way, I'm guessing any `sitemap.xml` file placed in `/wordpress` is probably never acknowledged.

Comment: Sooo... I think you are correct: the files need to be placed in root.  The explanation as to why, however, may be incorrect. I'm open to more clarifying insight.

Comment: Aah. I see you have removed your explanation.

Comment: Sorry if the last part of my answer was confusing. I removed it and will try to clarify.  robots.txt and sitemap.xml will need to be placed at the root of your domain as this is the first location where a robot will look when it visits your site. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.1

The WordPress htaccess rules actually do not matter when it comes to this.

Comment: I'll upvote. You did provide the correct yes/no answer.
An answer with references attached, or a proper explanation are always preferred, for learning and for verification. you *did* help me arrive at an understanding indirectly. Two days, and I did not get this far! So Thanks :-)

Comment: The only link I was referencing was the WordPress codex link in your question so I didn't feel it relevant to relink it, but I've changed my answer to include a link with further info.

Comment: Of course, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Huh. I see your updated answer and first comment now! I don't *want* it to crawl *anything* in (actual) root !  Only `/wordpress`. I don't understand, then, how to tell it not to crawl that root directory.  Because `/` as an address, *generally* refers to `/wordpress` in my settup. UGH.

Comment: You can set Disallow rules in the robots.txt file, everything but the /wordpress directory